# Attempting to concatenating data from multiple Excel files with Python but missing columns

Tags: python, pandas

```
path = "C:\\Users\\Adam\\Desktop\\Stock Trackers\\New Folder\\"

finalDf = pd.DataFrame()

for file in filenames:
    if file.startswith("Stock"): 
        df = pd.read_excel(path+file,usecols="A:D,R",index_col=None) 
        df['Total Received']
        df['Qty Received']=df['Total Received']
        df['InvoicedValue'] = df['Price']*df['Qty Invoiced']
        df['ReceivedValue'] = df['Price']*df['Qty Received']
        df['DeltaQty']= df['Qty Received']-df['Qty Invoiced']
        df['DeltaValue']= df['ReceivedValue']-df['InvoicedValue']
        finalDf = pd.concat([finalDf, df])
        finalDf.to_excel("finalfile12.xlsx")
```

The above script generates the below:

[image]

As you can see, the "Total Received" column is missing and so are columns that directly or indirectly dependent on this. The original files have data for these columns. Also, index_col=None is not removing the index in column A (index_col=False doesn't work either)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. Questions about debugging help need to include a [mre] including complete but minimal code as well as minimal example input and output as text, [not a picture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Although, just the process of working through the problem should help. If I were you, I'd start by printing the "Total Received" column for each `df` and make sure it's there. For specifics, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341). For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: Regarding *"index_col=None is not removing the index in column A"*, are you only looking at `finalfile12.xlsx`? It's going to have an index because you didn't supply `index=False` to `finalDf.to_excel()`.